# Databricks job widgets from ADLS file

Tags: widget, databricks, azure-databricks, jobs, databricks-workflows

I have a text widget in which user needs to feed in batch id say "201906", it is a year with month. So the data gets processed for this particular batch. So now how do I get this value from a CSV or a file name located in ADLS container and use it in a databricks dropdown widget so that the user will not have the freedom to enter a batchid which is not to be processed or restricted to process? So basically I want to give the option to the user with the required batch to be processed but not an entire field to type whatever he wants.

Comment: is this ADLS container mounted into Databricks workspace?

Comment: Yes @AlexOtt, it is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

It's just easy - you can use local file API to access file on DBFS, like this (you need to replace `dbfs:/` with `/dbfs/` to access file on DBFS):

```py
with open("/dbfs/tmp/my-batches.txt") as f:
  batches = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip() != ""]
    
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="batches", label="Select batch", 
     choices=batches, defaultValue=batches[0])
```

will give you what you need:

[image]

You can achieve the same by using the Spark API - it could be a bit slower, but it won't require that storage account is mounted - you can use `abfss://`, `wasbs://` and other supported protocols:

```py
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
df = spark.read.text("/tmp/my-batches.txt")
batches = [r[0].strip() for r in df.collect() if r[0].strip() != ""]   
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="batches", label="Select batch", 
     choices=batches, defaultValue=batches[0])
```